# C++ threads does not work as I expect?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am making bigger program where I want to use threads so as first I am trying to find out how threads actually work so I created a simple program and I can not understand why I do not get a message `"Bomberman has just put a bomb. Wait for the boom."` earlier than `"The bomb has just detonated."`.

Can anyone instruct me why is it not working as I expect?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class CBomberman;

class CBomb {
 public:
  CBomb(void) : m_Owner(nullptr) {
    thread other_thread(&CBomb::Timer, this);
    other_thread.join();
  }

 private:
  void Timer(void) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
    cout << "The bomb has just detonated." << endl;
  }

  CBomberman* m_Owner;
};

class CBomberman {
 public:
  CBomberman(void) : m_Bomb(nullptr) {}

  bool PutBomb(void) {
    if (m_Bomb == nullptr) {
      m_Bomb = new CBomb();
      delete m_Bomb;
      return true;
    } else {
      cout << "The bomb has already been put." << endl;
      return false;
    }
  }

 private:
  CBomb* m_Bomb;
};

int main() {
  CBomberman bomberman;

  bomberman.PutBomb();
  cout << "Bomberman has just put a bomb. Wait for the boom." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code you posted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I dont know what you are talking about.

Comment: Why all the extra whitespace in the function declaration?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie First few whitespaces are there because it is a space for return type.

Comment: Please [see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d70b3cad6acd3a0d).  That represents the same program, formatted in a way that most, if not all C++ programmers would expect.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you but I think it is a matter of a habit

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I gotta say, I currently work on a codebase which has code formatting standards similar to the OP. There's nothing objectively wrong with it (though I don't like it). Just copy-paste the code in your favorite text viewer and run it through clang-format.

Comment: Why do you delete m_Bomb right after creating it? Seems like a job for a destructor function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're joining the thread immediately after you create it, meaning that you're only using multithreading in a very technical sense: you've definitely created another thread, and it's (probably) going to operate on another CPU core, but the host thread is simply sitting idle while the other thread works.

You need to locally store the `thread` object so that you can join it at a later point.

```
class CBomb
{
public:
    CBomb ( void )
    : m_Owner ( nullptr ),
    bomb_thread(&CBomb::Timer, this)
    {
    }
    std::thread bomb_thread; //This needs to be a member of this object. Whether you make it public or not is a matter of your design approach.
private:
    void Timer ( void )
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::seconds( 3 ) );
        cout << "The bomb has just detonated." << endl;
    }

    CBomberman * m_Owner;
};

class CBomberman
{
public:
    CBomberman ( void )
    : m_Bomb ( nullptr )
    {

    }

    bool PutBomb ( void )
    {
        if( m_Bomb == nullptr )
        {
            m_Bomb = new CBomb();//Don't delete the object immediately after creating it. What were you expecting to have happen if you did?
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The bomb has already been put." << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    CBomb * m_Bomb;
};

int main()
{
    CBomberman bomberman;

    bomberman.PutBomb();
    cout << "Bomberman has just put a bomb. Wait for the boom." << endl;
    bomberman.m_bomb->bomb_thread.join(); //If we hit the end before the thread concludes, there could be some errors.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Man, perfect ! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm but it is really weird that when I use it the same way as I used it here in the much larger program, compilation fails with error: `error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(CBomb*))()>’`

Comment: @lolofon That sounds like a different, probably unrelated error. Post a new question with your new error. Also make sure you updated your access modifiers: my code moved some of your stuff from `private` to `public` to make the code easier to write.

Comment: It is hard to post it here. It has multiple files crossing each other.. When I think of how to post it, I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `join` on `other_thread` immediately after creating `other_thread`.  The `join` call blocks the main thread and waits for `other_thread` to exit.  See docs on std::thread::join at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join.

Comment: Can you tell me how to call `thread other_thread` in `int main()` with `bomberman . PutBomb()` without making `PutBomb()` `static`?

Comment: Store your thread locally. And join in the main() function.You can make it public or create getter.